# How safe are the new HTML5 input tags

Tags: html5

I am thinking to use the Input Type tags in my web application like

```
<input type="email">  
<input type="number" required="required">
```

I'm just curious how safe is to use them , Is there any options so the user will disable them from browser.

Comment: Are you asking about compatibility between different browsers, or are you asking if there are any security concerns?

Answer (score 2):

They are **not** safe.

You can **never** count on them being executed.

You **can't** skip server-side input-checking.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 is as safe as HTML4 for Input Methods, Your elements should be controlled by JavaScript or PHP and have them validate the data that the user is imputing. Your question is very broad and impossible to give you an exact answer because its not actually clear what your asking.

If your concerned about compatibility with the new HTML5 tags then you should use [HTML5Shiv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_Shiv) or [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) which contains best of both worlds.